# Number of features of the model must match the input in python

Tags: python, text-classification

I have created a model of text classifier using this link: https://stackabuse.com/text-classification-with-python-and-scikit-learn/ 
And then I tried to check it and use with my own data which is not it dataset. But, It says that number of features does not match.
Here my code for that:

```
import pickle 
with open('text_classifier', 'rb') as training_model:  
    model = pickle.load(training_model)

f = open(r".\descriptions_dataset\image\0.txt", "r")

test = f.read()
print(test)
f.close()

import re
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
stemmer = WordNetLemmatizer()
document = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(test))
document = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document)
document = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document) 
document = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', document, flags=re.I)
document = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', document)
document = document.lower()
document = document.split()
document = [stemmer.lemmatize(word) for word in document]
print(document)

nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer  
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=1500, min_df=1, max_df=0.7, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))  
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(document).toarray()

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer  
tfidfconverter = TfidfTransformer()  
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(X).toarray()  

y_pred = model.predict(X)
```

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 y_pred = model.predict(X)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in predict(self, X)
    541             The predicted classes.
    542         """
--> 543         proba = self.predict_proba(X)
    544 
    545         if self.n_outputs_ == 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in predict_proba(self, X)
    581         check_is_fitted(self, 'estimators_')
    582         # Check data
--> 583         X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
    584 
    585         # Assign chunk of trees to jobs

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X)
    360                                  "call `fit` before exploiting the model.")
    361 
--> 362         return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)
    363 
    364     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
    386                              "match the input. Model n_features is %s and "
    387                              "input n_features is %s "
--> 388                              % (self.n_features_, n_features))
    389 
    390         return X

ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 1500 and input n_features is 86

Comment: it could be helpful to paste the error message and the location of the error

Comment: yeah thanks, i pasted it